# Imprimir variável em div com javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola duvida talvez boba mas n estou conseguindo resolver pessoal, o seguinte tenho um determinado valor javascript (variavel) e preciso quando a pessoa entrar no site imprima essa variavel na DIV? por exemplo "ola mundo!" lembrando que essa variavel depois ira mudar automaticamente então fora de cogitação por fixo o valor .

```html
<div><p >Imprimir aqui</p></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nunca se esqueça de utilizar o `window.onload` para poder executar seu código `JavaScript` após os elementos HTML estarem prontos para serem manipulados.

Criei um exemplo para você ver a mudança em tempo real.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var myvar = "Olá mundo";

  document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = myvar;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (myvar == "Olá mundo") {
      myvar = "Mudando dinamicamente"
    } else {
      myvar = "Olá mundo"
    }

    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = myvar;
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Andrew Ribeiro cara vc me ajudou muto. Desde ja eu agradeço.